# How to change the title color in shinydashboard from server using shinyjs

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I want to change the title of header in shinydashboard, from the server part. Simple text, e.g. p(), can be changed, while it seems no changes in the title.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

header <- dashboardHeader(title='want to be red') |> 
        tagAppendAttributes(id='nn',.cssSelector = 'span')

side <- dashboardSidebar(
    useShinyjs(),
    inlineCSS(list('.red' = "color: red")),
    p(id = "p", "to red color")
)

body <- dashboardBody()

ui <- dashboardPage(header,side,body,title = 'nhanesR')

server <- function(input, output, session){
    toggleClass(id = 'nn', "red")
    toggleClass(id = 'p', "red")
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You forget to library `shinyjs`
2. Better to load shinyjs `useShinyjs()` in the body instead.
3. For the title, you can't simply add the red class. The original stylesheet has a stronger selector that will prevent you to change color. We need to use an inline style, which has the almost highest priority to overwrite the color.

```r
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
header <- dashboardHeader(title='want to be red') |> 
    tagAppendAttributes(id='nn',.cssSelector = 'span')

side <- dashboardSidebar(
    inlineCSS(list('.red' = "color: red")),
    p(id = "p", "to red color")
)

body <- dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs()
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header,side,body,title = 'nhanesR')

server <- function(input, output, session){
    runjs('$("#nn").css("color", "red")')
    toggleClass(id = 'p', "red")
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Unless you want to change it dynamically, not sure why you want to use shinyjs to do this. We can do all of this with `tags$style` on the UI.

[image]

Comment: Great Thanks for your answer, it not work in my PC, And I update all the packages to the latest. My R version is 4.1.0.

Comment: Let thanks for letting me know. They updated the `shinydashboard`. Now they change the selectors a little bit. I edited my answer, try again.

Comment: Great thanks.  The id selector seems not work here. class seleftor .logo works